# Python 3.5 or later is required when Python 3.10.7 is used

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-venv

I was trying to install [streisand](https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand) on my server (Linode) and I tried to execute the command `./util/venv-dependencies.sh ./venv` (from the installation docs) but I get an error:

```
Found a python3 command....


The python3 command invokes Python 3.10.7. Python 3.5 or later is
required.


On Debian, Ubuntu, and WSL:
   sudo apt install python3 python3-pip python3-virtualenv

On macOS:
   # If you haven't, install homebrew from https://brew.sh/
   brew install python

On other systems: please see your OS documentation on how to install
Python 3.
```

The server OS is Ubuntu Server

I tried running `sudo apt install python3 python3-pip python3-virtualenv` but it did not help. Thank you in advance

Comment: File a bug report with the library maintainers. This is not how you properly compare versions (from `venv-dependencies.sh`): `if [[ $python_version < "Python 3.5" ]]; then`

Comment: Right.  It was stupid to compare version numbers as strings.  It is easy for you to delete that check, however.

Comment: That project is dead. The devs abandoned it, the Github repo was archived two years ago, and their Twitter has had no activity since 2018. It will not receive maintenance. This will not be fixed.